# Why we get 2 groups created inside sharepoint when we create a new MS Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, microsoft-teams, office-365-groups

I have created a new MS Teams from my MS Teams desktop application, I name the new MS Team as "TestUserPermission":

[image]

Now this has created a new SharePoint site + a new Office 365 group behind the scene, which is fine.

But what makes me got confused is that inside SharePoint site we got 2 groups/entitties named "TestUserPermision Members" and "TestUserPermission Owners", the first will be added inside the SharePoint member group while the other will be defined inside the site collection admin group, as follow:-

[image]

[image]

So what are those 2 entries? and what is the relation between those 2 entries and the Office 365 group? do any of them represent the Office 365 group which got created for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple answer to your question:

When you create a new Team from Microsoft Teams or a new Team site from SharePoint, it creates a Microsoft 365 group. This Microsoft 365 group has 2 entities: **Group Owners** and **Group Members** as given in below image:

[image]

**Relation between SharePoint groups and M365 group**:

By default when M365 group is created it adds:

1. M365 group owners in SharePoint **Site Collection Administrators**
2. M365 group members in SharePoint default **Members** group which generally has name in format: `<Site Title> Members`

Comment: I think it should clear your doubts. let me know if you have ay question related to this.

Comment: ok thanks for the detailed description and info... but i have noted something, if i remove the "Group Members" entity from the "SharePoint members" group, then all the "Group Members" users will not have access to the SharePoint site which is logical.. but if i remove the "Group Owners" from the SharePoint site collection admins, then the "Group Owners" users will still get full permission on the site. so can i say that the users inside the "Group Owners" will always have full control permission on the SharePoint site regardless of any other settings!!??

Comment: True, I have also observed the same behavior in my developer tenant before. Not sure why it is like this. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it answered your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Within the SharePoint site, you have the owners, members and visitor groups. These are SharePoint groups. The members SharePoint group you have shown in your screenshot contains the Microsoft 365 group that was created when you created a Microsoft Team. It has the same name as your SharePoint members group. You can confirm this by clicking on that Microsoft 365 group and checking the object GUID against the object ID shown for your Microsoft 365 group inside Azure Active Directory.

The user that appears in your Site Collection Administrators group is a SP user which represents the owners of the Microsoft 365 group.

Comment: thanks for the reply... but what about the "TestUserPermision Owners" which got added inside the site collection admin? does this represent a separate office 365 group? or it contain the members inside the office 365 group who has admin role?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an explanation for this. If this answers your questions, please let the community know by marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: when you say `SP user which represents the owners of the Microsoft 365 group.` you mean all the users who have owner role inside the related office 365 group?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.